# My server hanged by exception in stored procedure. Timeout expired

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I wrote a cursor within a stored procedure which is basically like this:

```
OPEN curr

    Fetch NEXT FROM curr into @ID, @IsCC, @JurisdictionID

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        --Code for Update and Insert operations
         Fetch NEXT FROM curr into @ID, @IsCC, @JurisdictionID
    End

    CLOSE curr
    DEALLOCATE  curr
```

Now in the While loop I got exception for one of the Insert statements for Foreign Key violation. So I fixed it but after this exception when I try to run my application it just couldn't run even simplest of the queries and I keep getting `Timeout expired`. Only after I restarted my Sql Server service all seems to start properly.

My guess is the statement CLOSE and DEALLOCATE didn't run after I hit with the exception. What do I do if such a case occurs? I am frightened if this happens in production I will be smashed like a piece of potato.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Comment: @David: But why should I handle try catch in stored procedure? I have handled it in my C# code. Further doesn't SQL server keep executing code even if exception fires? T-SQL is not like C# code I guess where, when you hit with exception your next line doesn't execute. I guess next line SQL is executed but @@Error global variable is set? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why do you need a cursor for UPDATE and INSERT operations?

Comment: Can you rewrite your statement to avoid the cursor? Do you update / insert a large number of records? What data access components do you use? If it's `ADO.NET`, the `SqlCommand` has a default of 30 seconds. You can increase it, but that won't solve the underlying problem. Check for locks as well.

Comment: marc_s: because I have bulk operations going on and I pass my user defined type in stored procedure (DataTable from C#) and I have other complex operations going on.

Comment: @dradu: Yes it's bulk insert/update based on IFs and Thens

Comment: T-SQL can handle bulk operations just fine - without any messy cursor ... bulk (and set-based) operations is what T-SQL excels at ...

Comment: Can I write IFs and Thens without cursor within Insert and Update statement? Note I am not talking about Case When. I guess not! Further whether I want to write insert or update statement also depends upon IFs and Then.

Comment: If you are simply wishing to determine if you need to update or insert a record, then do a search on UPSERT, or given you've tagged the question with SS 2008, then look at MERGE. This could certainly save you a heap of time. SET based operations are what you want to stick with whenever you can.

Comment: @Mr Moose: Thanks. I will have a look at it now.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/2924048/685760 as another way of using merge for batch updates. Sommorskog's site has some other great examples if Table Value Parameters don't suit your situation.

Comment: Were you tracing this query when you hit this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, how is your code looking, but usually peoples can get this type of behavior if they have a bad exception handling, and the connection to the database is still there.

If those two commands did not run, you should get the following exceptions from this code only: 
by creation:
A cursor with the name 'curr' already exists.

and by the opening:
The cursor is already open.

I think you should make the exceptionhandling from database level more secure.